# The problem about jquery $.ajax get value xml file

Tags: jquery, ajax, coding-style, head

I want use $.ajax get a url string from a xml file ,then with the url getted,I insert it into a style link ,then let the link insert into the `<head>`,I write code like this:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "get",
     url: "Database/App_all.xml",
     dataType: "html",
     timeout: 2000,
     success: function (xml) {
     var $tid='id-5';
    //alert($tid);
     var $temp_private_css = $(xml).find("app[id='" + $tid + "']").find("css").text();
     if ($temp_private_css.length > 0) {
    //alert($temp_private_css);
     $('head').append('<link href="' + $temp_private_css + '" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
         }
     },
     error: function () { }
});
```

However ,the result is in my firebug

```
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="' + $temp_private_css + '">
```

I use alert function to see whether the $temp_private_css get value,it shows correct like "Database/css/test.css",it just could't insert into the head

why this happened?How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call that on document ready, like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
         type: "get",
         url: "Database/App_all.xml",
         dataType: "html",
         timeout: 2000,
         success: function (xml) {
         var $tid='id-5';
        //alert($tid);
         var $temp_private_css = $(xml).find("app[id='" + $tid + "']").find("css").text();
         if ($temp_private_css.length > 0) {
         //alert($temp_private_css);
         $('head').append('<link href="' + $temp_private_css + '" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
             }
         },
         error: function () { }
    });
});
```

So that it adds the proper stylesheet to the DOM.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Why I have to put it in $(document).ready?Actually I already put it in $(function(){}); but in a function,like function tests(){},but it still does't work

Comment: Because $(document).ready(function... will run once the DOM is ready and items can be added.  If you run your functions beforehands, they mean nothing to the DOM/what the user sees.  Here is some more information on it:  http://api.jquery.com/ready/  Hope this helps.  Let me know

Comment: Thank you I got it,.Then I put this code in the end of my page ,it work again